# VB.NET - Como apagar arquivos sendo usados por outro processo

Tags: vb.net

Olá, eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma dentro do VB.NET (Uso o Visual Studio 2017 [WinForm] ) de deletar um arquivo sendo usado por outro processo, no caso, excluir forçadamente o arquivo, mesmo que possa prejudicar o processo que o estava utilizando, por favor, alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer isso? Estou precisando muito pra um novo projeto.

Answer (score 1):

**O sistema operacional bloqueia o arquivo e você não vai conseguir mudar isso.**

Esse tipo de situação normalmente ocorre quando o arquivo está sendo usado por outro usuário, ainda que no mesmo computador, ou em outro computador pelo compartilhamento de arquivos.

Você tem algumas alternativas:

> Quando for no mesmo computador:

1. Finalizar o processo que está usando o arquivo. (Se usuários diferentes, o usuário deve ter permissão para tal)

> Quando for arquivo compartilhado:

2. Tentar renomear o arquivo. (Normalmente funciona em Windows Server, em SO clientes não posso te confirmar isso)
3. Parar o serviço do windows `Server`, que interrompe o compartilhamento, apagar o arquivo e então iniciar o serviço novamente. (Ao parar o `Server` o serviço `Pesquisador de computadores` também será parado. Lembre-se de inicializar os dois. Não acho recomendada essa alternativa, pois pode causar efeitos indesejados aos usuários, talvez sendo necessária intervenção de suporte técnico)